# Creating composite vairables in Structural Equation Modeling

Tags: spss, structural-equation-modeling, composite, amos

I was wondering if you can help me.  I want to run a pathway model using composite variables. Each composite variable is made up of 3 or 4 observed items. To create the composite variable to draw my model in AMOS do I simply compute the variable in SPSS by adding up the observed items relevant to each composite variable. Or do I use the data imputation option in AMOS to create my composite variable? Is there a preferred method

Comment: If you are asking how to use AMOS, that would be off-topic here. You don't need a composite variable, however. Add a latent variable that all the observed items measure.

Comment: @gung, consider converting to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a composite variable in a structural equations model.  Instead, add a latent variable that the manifest variables (i.e., the items) all measure.  The composite variable isn't what the items measure, it is just (presumably) a better measure of the latent variable in question.  If you were to add a composite variable, it would decrease the ability of your model to extract the information in your data, as it forces the loadings to be 1, whereas the latent variable will allow the loadings to be estimated from the data.

Comment: *it would almost certainly degrade your model's fit* -- yes and no; you will have fewer moments to fit, and the model structure will be different. Consider an SEM with two latent variables, regressed on one another, and with a sufficient number of indicators. The full model may not fit well because of cross-loadings or measurement error correlations. On the other hand, if you make composite variables of all of the indicators of each latent variable, then you will end up with a regression model in two variables that has zero SEM degrees of freedom and hence a perfect fit ...

Comment: ... so the composite variables is a way to sweep lack of fit under the carpet. ('twas too long for one comment)

Comment: @StasK, it seems like that would improve the fit by biasing the model. I have changed the answer; see if you think it's better now.

Comment: Thank you -- it is more specific now as to what the mechanics of the composite variables are.

Comment: @StasK Thank you so much for your helpful insight. You are right a pathway model would be an almost perfect fit of a structural model that uses latent variables. I am writing my PhD and I need to explore, discuss and explain that I have used both pathway models and latent structural models so that I can demonstrate that I know the pitfalls for both and to show the examiners I understand how to interpret the models.

Comment: @StasK But my question is more general and basic. In moving from a CFA model to a pathway model...what is the best way to turn my latent variables (made up of 3 or 4 observed items) to a pathway model that uses composite vairables (i.e. not latents but a sum score)? Shall I use Amos option of data imputation or shall I manually create the variable in SPSS and use it in AMOS?

Comment: I do understand the problems with using composite variables in models. But for the thesis I need to show I have used both pathway models and structural models and then discuss the pitfalls. But it seems researchers are in debate as to how best to create the composite variable as there are different methods. I am between computing new variable option in SPSS and data imputation option in AMOS. Does it make a difference which method to use to create this variable? One is manual and uses raw score and the latter I think uses means - Not sure :(

Comment: @Masa, writing three long comments is not the best way for discussion, and I won't be answering them. Synthesize them and either update your original question, or post a new one.

Comment: In addition @Masa, your new (?) questions in these comments seem to be only about how to use AMOS. As such, they would be off-topic for CV.

Comment: @StasK I dont think there was a need to respond in such a way. It is the first time I use this website so unfamiliar with the process! I believe my question was clear. How to create a composite variable to use in SEM - compute option in SPSS or in AMOS using the data imputation option? In any case I posted a new question if you want to help then that is up to you but no offense intended in my posts. Good day.

Comment: I am certain StasK didn't mean to come off harshly, @Masa. Be aware that CV is not a forum; it is a pure Q&A site. Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), which has information for new users.

Comment: @gung I am certain that you and StasK have made this experience on this site frustrating, a waste of time and not to mentioned it angered me beyond belief. Just because you did not understand the question or you do not know how to respond does not give you the right to put others down online. I am closing my account as I have found this experience a waste of time. Good luck to you both. Oh and see an example of literature on my question in my other question maybe that will clarify that it is ON topic.